# Checking data type for each variable in a R data frame

Tags: r, loops, sapply

I wondered what causes the differences between these 2 commands:

```
apply(DF,2,is.numeric)
c(ID = FALSE, diet = FALSE, height = FALSE, weight = FALSE, gender = FALSE, 
wohn = FALSE, social = FALSE, alter = FALSE, d13C = FALSE, d15N = FALSE, 
ferr = FALSE, VitB = FALSE)

sapply(DF,is.numeric)
c(ID = FALSE, diet = FALSE, height = TRUE, weight = TRUE, gender = FALSE, 
wohn = FALSE, social = FALSE, alter = TRUE, d13C = TRUE, d15N = TRUE, 
ferr = TRUE, VitB = TRUE)
```

I thought I could use the first one for data frames too?
Many thanks

Comment: Why not lapply(df, class)? Never use apply on data frame. It coerces the first argument to matrix, so if there is a single character col then they are all character.

Comment: I know the command str ( ), it was just a basic question related to the use for apply-foos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` changes the data to matrix first and since matrix can hold data of only one type if the dataframe has mixed class (numeric, character) it changes the numeric columns to character values thus returning `FALSE` for `is.numeric`.

Here's an example to demonstrate what you are observing.

```
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
apply(DF, 2, is.numeric)

#    a     b 
#FALSE FALSE 

sapply(DF, is.numeric)

#    a     b 
# TRUE FALSE
```

In contrast, if all the columns of dataframe is numeric `apply` will return `TRUE`.

```
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
apply(DF, 2, is.numeric)

#   a    b 
#TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks,
So apply ( ) should not be used with data frames. But this is bit sad.
so lapply is ok or it's "derivate"  sapply?
I used to work with apply and data frames before, nothing complex. But today I came across the first time were a releasized there's a mistake in it.

Comment: My rule of thumb is never use `apply(df, 2, ...)`. Whenever I want to apply a function column wise I prefer to use `sapply`/`lapply`.